# Auth guard with observable?

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

Okay suppose I have auth guard.
I want to do just a simple thing: send request to backend, in case it sends me user info that means user is authenticated, I want to return true. Else it will send me the error, so I want to catch that error and redirect user.
How do I do it in with rxjs? It seems overcomplicated...
What I want to do is to check whether user is logged in and whether his token is valid. So I understand that I need to send a request but how to manager error or response in general then? I understand too, that if there is no token in local storage, I should return false and shouldn't even send any request.
Of course this doesn't work but I don't know how to do it at all...

```
// guard
return this.authService.checkUserAuthenticated();
// service
checkUserAuthenticated() {
    this.http.post(`${this.domainName}api/auth/userinfo`, null)
      .subscribe(
      (data) => true,
    (err) => false
      );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can make an api call to the backend using authguard then return true or false

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private service:Service) {}

    canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        this.service.Authenticate().subscribe(
             (data: any)=>{ any condition to check and then return true},
             (error: any)=>{ return false;});

    }
}
```

and add authguard authentication method to the routing file.

Comment: nice, but what if I just come to start page and need no check whether user is logged in? I don't want to log him in, I need to check if he has been already logged in and if his token is still valid.

Comment: First alternative: you can create another class name it anything then call that one on the home-page route.
Second alternative: do authentication part on backend then return data in such format that you can check it here in `(data: any)=>{}` block